# Check whether an object is from a generic type(regardless of generic parameters types)

Tags: c#, generics, casting

```
public class Pair<T, U>
{
    public T Key { get; set; }
    public U Value { get; set; }

    public Pair(T key, U value)
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (Key is Pair<object, object>)
        {
            return $"{Key} which is the key to {Value}";
        }
        return $"{Key} is the key to {Value}";
    }
}
```

In the if statement inside ToString() I want to just check out whether Key is a Pair or not, T and U may be of any type.

I used object in here as both type parameters of Pair but I'm not getting inside the if.

Comment: You can use reflection here or make base non-generic class or interface. `Pair<object, object>` doesn't work due to generic variance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a reflection for that and check that underlying `Key` type is generic and has a `Pair<,>` [generic definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition?view=netcore-3.1)

```cs
public override string ToString()
{
    var type = Key.GetType();
    if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Pair<,>)))
    {
        return $"{Key} which is the key to {Value}";
    }
    return $"{Key} is the key to {Value}";
}
```

`Key is Pair<object, object>` will work only when `T` and `U` have `object` type, because in C# classes doesn't support a generic variance (only interfaces and delegates have such possibility)